# How does one reference the values of a ref of nested objects in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a reference to a data object in Vue. It is structured this way.

```
interface Plot {
  length: number,
  width: number,
  acreage: number
}
const model = {
   plot: ref<Plot[]>([]),
})
```

I make a call to get an array of plots. How do I set the individual plots? Some plots may not be valid, so I need to check that acreage is present before I put them.

I want to be able to do,

```
// This is only way it seems it can be set
model.plots.value = plots
// I would like to do this but don't know how
for( let plot of plots ){
  if(plot.length && plot.width && plot.acreage){
  // set the individual values in the Ref<Plot>          
}
```

Comment: why not [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `plots` first before assigning to `model.plots.value`

Comment: I will filter the result, but is there a way to do what I want ton achieve. I have some deep refs and would like to be able to achieve that if possible

Comment: as long as you access the actual value of the ref with `.value` you can treat an array of refs just like any other array of objects.

Comment: Is it possible to destructure the array? That's what I am asking, if possible how?

Answer (score 0):

I Might misunderstood the question, but I'll try to answer what I did understand from your question.

What you can do is to use a `filter` function plus a `map` function.

```js
model.plots.value = plots
  // 1. filter out all plots that have no values
  // please note, that if they have 0 as value, they will also be
  // filtered out with your if condition.
  .filter((plot) => plot.length && plot.width && plot.acreage)

  // 2. map the current structure to the final structure.
  .map((plot) => ({
    // return your target structure here...
  }))
```

Maybe you can update your question a bit with more code, that the context can be understood better. Because it is not obvious, because at the top you have `model.plot` and in the second example you use `model.plots`.